# mPDF - Content from specific div that is visible + add a save button

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

So I'm trying to set mPDF on my site, but the thing is, on the page that I want to create pdfs on, I get all of the content inside divs based on the posts count. So it looks something like this:

```
<div id="all-posts">
    <div id="some-post">
        content
    </div>
    <div id="some-other-post">
        content
    </div>
    <div id="post-with-long-title">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I have a select, with options values which are equal to the div IDs inside all-posts. And when you pick an option from the select, that div is showed. Now what I need to do is show a Save PDF button, and when that is clicked, get the content from the div that is currently showing (based on whats selected in select tag) and save the .pdf. Is something like this even possible?

### Update:

```
<?php include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();
ob_start(); ?>

<div id="all-posts">
        <div id="some-post">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="some-other-post">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="post-with-long-title">
            content
        </div>
    </div>

// Now collect the output buffer into a variable
<?php $html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit; ?>
```

Comment: @barell Could you help me with that?

Comment: Can you post your code you wrote so far?

Comment: @barell I updated the question with the code. I got something like this, and it worked but it generated all the divs inside. And also the PDF didnt show in chrome, like it wasnt a proper pdf file or something.